# Pass image with route.params React native

Tags: react-native, navigation, routeparams

I try to pass an Image with route.params, but it doesn't work.

From screen Number one I pass the result like this:

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Save', saveImage(), {result} )}
```

My screen number two their I try to display my image I do like this:

```
 <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${props.route.params.result}` }}/>
```

I get my result by printscreen a View and if I console.log my Image on screen One I get my result, but if console.log on screen number it says "undefined".

This how I save my image and this work:

```
  const saveImage = async () => {
  const image = await captureRef(inputEl, {
      result: 'base64',
      quality: 1,
      format: 'png',
    });
    setResult(image);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggest you this code :

```
    const saveImage = async () => {
       var  image = null
       image = await captureRef(inputEl, {
             result: 'base64',
             quality: 1,
             format: 'png',
       });
   if(image) return image ;
  };

 const goSaveImage = () => {
    saveImage().then((image)=>{
      props.navigation.navigate('Save', {result : image} )
    })
 }
```

and on your onPress :

```
onPress={() => goSaveImage()}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should navigate in useEffect.

```html
useEffect(() => {
  if (result) {
    props.navigation.navigate('Save', result)
  }
}, [result])

onPress={saveImage}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It was tough to find... but very simple.... using `route.params`

*e.g. Screen 1 & Screen 2*

**For Screen 1:**
create `useState` Hook i.e. `const [image, setImage] = useState(null);` and also don't forget to import `useState`, `useEffect`, from REACT. also Import `useNavigation` and `useRoute` from `@react-navigation/native`.

Example of `useState`:

```
export default function Screen1() { 
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [cnic, setCNIC] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [pv, setPV] = useState("");
  const [experience, setExperience] = useState("");
};
```

Create const for navigation between screens. `const navigation = useNavigation();`

Create another `const` to get data on another screen.

Example to send `data` on another screen:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

const userform = () => {
navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
profile: image,
name: name,
age: age,
cnic: cnic,
gender: gender,
category: category,
pv: pv,
experience: experience,
});
};
```

In the above mentioned code **Format** is the Screen 2 name. Where to pass the below data including `image`.

On Button `onPress = {userform}` which is `const` in the above mentioned code. It will navigate you to another screen and pass the given data accordingly.

For the `TextInput` use code `onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}`

**Screen 2:**

```
Import {useRoute} from "@react-navigation/native";
```

create `const` i.e.

```
export default function Screen2() {
const route = useRoute();
return (
<View>
      <Text>{route.params.name}</Text>         // For the TextInput Example
<Image 
      source = {{uri: route.params.profile}}   // For the Image Example
/>
</View>
)
};
```

The `route.params` should be the same as the `useState` hook on **Screen 1**.
With this method you can navigate between the screens also pass data including uploaded profile image into the format.

I hope this will help someone. Thank you

[Screen 1 "User Form"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7xc5.png)

[Screen 2 "Out Form"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpnc.png)